# Filter with ng model not working angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters, angularjs-ng-model

I have tried to implement a filter on angular tree with all corresponding nodes opening while filtering. Could you help me please ?

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6c1mg3od/1/

What I have tried so far (without success) :

```
<treenode ng-repeat="n in nodes|filter:node" node=n></treenode>
<input autofocus focus-me="true" type="text" data-ng-model="node" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
```

Comment: where is input in fiddle?

Comment: There is no input in fiddle. But I have add two lines of code in my post with the input that you can add in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This works just as expected (updated your jsfiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/6c1mg3od/4/

```
<div class=panel-left>
    <tree nodes="nodes | filter:node"></tree>
    <input type="text" ng-model="node">
</div>
```

Comment: Not completely. If you are looking for **Ultrabooks** for instance, I would like **Computers** and **Laptops** opening  while filtering.

Comment: FurtherMore, in console (F12) there is an error about $rootscope.. Do you know why please ?

Comment: Yes, it's the way the directives are made, triggering infinite digest

Comment: Ah.. I'm not an expert in angular..do you know please a cleaner way to achieve same result ? With dynamic filtering too?

Comment: Any particular reason why you use old angular 1.2?